# Setting up SQLite database for cluster analysis

Tags: python, sqlite, cluster-analysis, database-performance

I'm completely new to databases. I'd like to get some advice on how to set up and use a SQLite database for cluster analysis and topic modeling tasks.

I have a 2 GB file where each line is a json object. Here is an example json object from the file:

```
{"body": "Heath Ledger's Joker...", "subreddit_id": "t5_2qh3s", "name": "t1_clpmhgo", "author": "l3thaln3ss", "created_utc": "1414799999", "subreddit": "movies", "parent_id": "t3_2kwdi3", "score": 1, "link_id": "t3_2kwdi3", "sub_type": "links - high"}
```

I have created a SQLite database like so:

```
import json
import sqlite3
import sys

def main(argv):
    if len(argv) != 2:
        sys.exit("Provide a database name.")

    dbName = argv[1]
    db = sqlite3.connect(dbName)

    db.execute('''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Comments
              (name text primary key,
               author text,
               body text,
               score integer,
               parent_id text,
               link_id text,
               subreddit text,
               subreddit_id text,
               sub_type text,
               created_utc text,
               foreign key (parent_id) references Comment(name));''')

    db.commit()
    db.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main(sys.argv)
```

Is this a good initial setup for the database?

I am populating the database like so:

```
import json
import sqlite3
import sys

def main(argv):
    if len(argv) != 2:
        sys.exit("Provide a comment file (of json objects) name.")

    fname = argv[1]

    db = sqlite3.connect("commentDB")
    columns = ['name', 'author', 'body', 'score', 'parent_id', 'link_id', 'subreddit', 'subreddit_id', 'sub_type', 'created_utc']

    query = "insert or ignore into Comments values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)"

    c = db.cursor()

    with open(fname, 'r') as infile:
        for comment in infile:
            decodedComment = json.loads(comment)
            keys = ()
            for col in columns:
                keys += (decodedComment[col],)
            print str(keys)
            print
            c.execute(query, keys)

    c.close()
    db.commit()
    db.close()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main(sys.argv)
```

Ultimately, I'm going to be clustering subreddits based on shared frequent words in comments, which users comment where, and differences in topic models obtained by analyzing the words found in subreddit comments. Note that I have many more 2 GB files I'd like to work in, so ideally a solution should be relatively scalable. Any general advice on how to setup (especially by improving what I have written) the database to do this sort of work would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Edit: removed question about insert performance.

Comment: See [SQLite FAQ #19](http://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q19). Don't commit after every insert. Get a cursor once instead, then loop and insert, and commit once after you're done inserting.

Comment: @LukasGraf: Thanks for the reference. I have fixed when I was committing and it is much more efficient. My other general question about setting up the database still remains.

Comment: There's nothing *inherently* wrong with your setup, but the scalability aspect of your question is so broad, it's not a very good fit for StackOverflow's Q&A format. Nobody will be able to predict how your setup (and your code doing the analysis!) will scale - so it's almost impossible to give a correct answer here. You should rather start with what you have, and *if* you hit a performance problem, use the tools available to you to determine where the problem lies - or ask a new, specific question on SO.

Comment: SQLite itself may not scale well for that amount of data. You might want to use [SQLAlchemy](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/) (just the core, not the ORM) instead of the DBAPI directly to write code that is abstracted from a particular database backend, and then switch over from SQLite to a "real DB" when you hit its limits.

Comment: The other thing is: It may even be the case that a relational DB still isn't ideal for this sort of task. You may want to look into indexing your data into [ElasticSearch](https://www.elastic.co/products/elasticsearch) and using a clustering engine like [carrot2](https://github.com/carrot2/elasticsearch-carrot2) to do the clustering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several minor improvements suggest themselves -- e.g, the `CREATE TABLE` for `Comments` has a `references Comment(name)` where I'm pretty sure `Comment` is a mis-spelling and you meant `Comments` (so your code as posted wouldn't work).

Speed-wise, building the peculiarly-named `keys` as a `tuple` is somewhat wasteful -- a `list` would be much better, i.e, replace

```
        keys = ()
        for col in columns:
            keys += (decodedComment[col],)
```

with

```
        keys = [decodedComment[col] for col in columns]
```

for slightly better performance (it's not clearly documented, perhaps, but the cursor's `execute` method takes a second arg that's a list just as happily as it takes a tuple).

But overall you have a good start -- and should be fine after ingesting a single 2GB input file.  **However**, sqlite, awesome as it is in many respects, doesn't really scale up well for multiples of that size -- you'll need a "real" database for that.  I'd recommend `PostgreSQL` but probably `MySQL` (and its variants such as `MariaDB`) and commercial (non-open-source) offerings would be just fine too.

If by "many more" (2GB files) you mean hundreds, or thousands, even "serious" professional DBs might at some point start creaking at the seams, depending on what processing, exactly, you plan to throw at them; the mention of "every word in the comment" (implying I imagine the `body` field needs to be processed -- stemming &c -- into a collection of words) is slightly worrisome in promising very heavy processing to come.

Once that becomes a problem, "NoSQL" offerings, or stuff **seriously** meant to scale up such as e.g BigQuery, may be worth your while.  However, for small-scale experimentation, you can surely start with sqlite and use it to develop the algorithms for the "clustering" you have in mind; then scale up to PostgreSQL or whatever to check how those scale on middle-scale work; only at that point, if need be, take the extra work to consider non-relational solutions, which, while very powerful, tend to require commitment to certain patterns of access (relational DBs, where the most you likely need is to add indices, are likely more suitable for more experimental-stage play!).

Comment: Thanks for this very helpful response (and catching that typo). It gives me a good idea of how to move forward and what is out there. Concerning processing comment bodies: I need to make term histograms of each comment. Would it be feasible to replace each comment's body with a word-histogram (say just a dictionary with words as keys and their counts as values) in the table? Also, what is "stemming &c"?

Comment: @Dimitrios, "dictionaries" aren't really part of a relational database's model of life, the Universe, and everything -- every field is a scalar (a single number, string, date, or the like) and the only kind container is a table (you get to do "joins" across tables to reconstruct things, but that gets a bit intricate and is well worth of a separate Q!-).  Maybe only keep the top ten most-frequent non-stopwords per comment, that's easier.  Re stemming see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stemming -- essentially collapsing words like "dog" and "dogs" into the single stem "dog"...

Answer (score 1):

Traditional SQL and NoSQL databases are not particularly useful for such an analysis. The lack the ability to allow fine gained similarities, or the ability to accelerate queries as needed by clustering algorithms.

In most practical use you will end up with a workflow like this:

1. Load the data from the database into the analysis application (often by dumping it into some CSV format)
2. Perform the analysis
3. Write the result back into the database

This is not very pretty or efficient, and will surely disappoint you. But given the lack of analytical flexibility even in commercial offers, it's all we've got. And even the analytical functionality available in some commercial offers - of it were of sufficient functionality - often works this way.

In your particular use case it may be possible to use Lucene as a backing database. If you have a clustering algorithm *and* implementation that can be accelerated by Lucene queries, that is.